# android how to crop using an existent image

Tags: android, crop

I need to crop an image using selectors and dragging etc.
I cannot use com.android.camera.action.CROP cause in many phones i tested doesn't work.
I searched here all examples, the only working is that where is used android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
but the problem is that everytime it asks user to choice the image.
Can someone post me kindly an example.
I need to open it on the image i need, without that the user has to open an image, searching in file system.
I am enough disappointed cause android doestn offer something compatible for all devices from  2.1 android till 4 at least... 
Thanks

Comment: For me is ok also an example where i can do the crop by myself overriding on draw using a view in layout and getting coordinates .

Answer (score 0):

Download Sample:- https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/AndroidImageCrop

Only three changes required for android 2.1:-

1. In main.xml, write wrap_content instead of matchparent.
2. In AndroidManifest.xml, `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />`
3. In default.properties, `target=android-7`

A project is a best tutor.